# Script only work for newest posts

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I have this script that pulls facebook likes from the Facebook Graph and uses them as meta values for posts. And it works. The problem is that it only updates the meta values for the 5 newest posts, and I can't figure out why.

*What I've done:* I tried to install the script on a brand new Wordpress install, no plugins, default twenty twelve theme, localhost but the issue persisted.

**Full Script here:** http://pastebin.com/f6LqgqQS 
**Site URL:** http://wisefiction.com/recent 
 (might load slowly, the script runs on init now instead of wp_cron for debugging purposes. If you like/unlike the posts and reload the page you'll see that fb_likes_count only changes for the top 5 posts)

```
        $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_mime_type'   => '',
            'post_status'      => 'publish'
    );
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

    foreach($posts_array as $post):

            $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);

    $idpost = $post->ID;

    $data = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id='.$permalink);

    $json = $data;

    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $like_no = $obj->{'shares'};

    $meta_values = get_post_meta($idpost, 'fb_likes_count', true);

    if($like_no == null){$like_no = 0;}

    update_post_meta($idpost, 'fb_likes_count', $like_no, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `posts_per_page` argument in your `get_posts` parameters.  Set it to -1 to retrieve all posts.  See [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Usage).

Comment: I tried it now and it seems to work partly. Out of 60 posts, 40 were now affected. When I mass posted in localhost, I got a "file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403" error. But after 5 minutes, everything went back to normal and **all** posts were affacted. But then again, I could only request one graph url in localhost. But would it be right to assume that the reason not all posts are affected is because file_ get_contents gets overloaded by too many posts?

Comment: Not really sure.  But if it's intermittent, I would guess Facebook are limiting the number of requests you can make.  Seems more likely than `file_get_contents` failing to work your machine.  403 means it was forbidden by the remote server.

Comment: Yes, I just checked back again now and almost all posts are affected now, not all though but it seems to vary. I'll mark this answer as accepted answer as it did solve the initial issue. I'll try to find a way to run the script for one post at a time, and only when someone clicks on the like button. That would limit the requests. Or I could try cURL, would that limit the requests too?

Comment: Thanks for accepting.  I'd check Facebooks' conditions, to see if they mention a limit, then maybe add a `sleep` to throttle your requests.  My guess is cURL would have the same problem, since it's a problem on the Facebook side.  If I were you I'd open a new question (assuming a search doesn't help), since this is a new problem.